# Visual Basic: How can I have an integer in a variable?

Tags: vb.net, string, variables

I apologize if the question is a bit bland, but what I'm trying to do is access a list of things from a text file like "R1", "R2", "R3". Is it possible that I can have the integer in that name as a seperate variable?

So if I have...

```
Dim R0 As String = "Hello"
Dim R1 As String = "Goodbye"

Dim RCount As Integer = 0

MsgBox(R & RCount) 'Returns Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Not without creating and evaluating an [Expression Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882536.aspx), but you could use an array and an index into the array.

```
Dim R(6) as String

R(0) = "Hello"
R(1) = "Goodbye"

Dim RCount as Integer = 0

MsgBox(R(RCount))
```